# Why does my pydoc command retrieve a exception.syntaxerror?

Tags: python, syntax-error, pydoc

I a beginner level python user and when I type the following in the terminal:

$ pydoc Inleesgenbank.py

I get the following error message:

problem in ./Inleesgenbank.py - : invalid syntax (Inleesgenbank.py, line 30)

So at line 30 there must be a syntaxis error in this code:

```
def usage(msg1=''):
    """Levert de docstring met een foutspecificatie bij een gebruikersfout"""
    print(__doc__, file=sys.stderr)
    if len(msg1) > 0:
        print('FOUTMELDING:', msg1, file=sys.stderr)
```

Line 30 is the line: `print(__doc__, file=sys.stderr)`

I know this is not a very clean piece of code but I want to learn what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get a syntax error running on Python 3, but I do get a syntax error on Python 2.  You are using the Python 3 print syntax.

For Python 2 you should use:

```
print >> sys.stderr, usage.__doc__
```

Note also that you probably meant `usage.__doc__`

Comment: You are right, when I use pydoc3 instead of pydoc I don't get an errormessage. So I assume the shebang does not work for the pydoc command.

Comment: The shebang line is only used when a script is run directly.  So your #! line should have had pydoc3 in it, and you should not call it using pydoc, but directly using `Inleesgenbank.py`.  This applies to most scripting languages, not just pydoc, or even python.